# Sesame in-memory triple store

Tags: semantic-web, triplestore, sesame

```
- Using openrdf-sesame-latest
- Using in-memory repository in Sesame Standalone Server
- Using REST api interface (SPARQL queries) to Sesame Standalone server
- Have few hundred thousands triples for now
- have 16GB of memory on Sesame Server
- Moderate writes and reads
```

I am just looking for opinions/help here from the experts

I started this as a POC and build my application on top of it. I am looking at 4Stores and Mulgara, Alleograph (free) options.

- Given my less experience, I was wondering when would it be absolutley
  mandatory for me to move away from Sesame Server.
- Would it be scale, security, write/read peformance etc?
- If I only have, lets say, 100,000 triples, do I ever need to move to some other store and why?
- I intend to use it for production use-case as well.

Its just that I am trying avoid invest time in migrating unless its absolutely needed. Let me put it another way "Can I use openrdf-sesame-latest Standalone server with in-memory repository (16GB) in production? If not, why not?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Being one of the Sesame developers, I'm obviously biased, but I don't see why you couldn't.

Sesame is successfully used in many production environments. The memory store scales with the amount of available RAM, and although I have personally never tested it with more than a couple of million triples, I expect you can continue addding without significant performance loss as long as you don't run out of heap space. You mention 100,000 triples, which is tiny, Sesame can easily cope with orders of magnitude larger datasets.

An advantage of Sesame is also that it is really not a single triplestore, but a framework and API that supports multiple storage backends. For anything up to, say, 150 million triples, the Sesame native store is a good solution (better persistence, less memory footprint, which are perhaps good reasons to use this even if the amount of data you have would fit in memory).

If you need to go beyond that, there are several other options, including third-party triplestores such as OWLIM or BigData, that support the Sesame APIs - so even if you find you need a bigger triplestore you won't have to change much at code level - you simply plug in a different store.